# AngularJS not displaying objects inside of an array from MongoDB

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb

AngularJS will not display the "tracking" entry in my data structure. It shows tracking as "tracking": [] as an empty array in the HTML template, and when its console.log'd.

My API returns the following data structure:

```
[{
"_id": "57e96aaa45b09843a53a4dcd",
"phase": 1,
"notes": "asdf",
"treatment": "asdf",
"patientname": "asdf",
"__v": 0,
"tracking": [
    {
    "modifiedby": "Person",
    "action": "Created",
    "_id": "57e96aaa45b09843a53a4dce",
    "modifiedat": "2016-09-26T18:36:26.281Z"
    }
]
}]
```

In AngularJS I have the following factory:

```
getwaiting: function(callback){
        $http.get('/pre-auth/getwaitingsubmit').then(function success(data){
            return callback(data.data)
        })
    }
```

In my controller:

```
WaitingFactory.getwaiting(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $scope.waitinglist = data;
    });
```

When I do {{waitinglist}} in my HTML template, it displays the ALL of the data except "tracking". It displays tracking as: "tracking":[], I cant access the data by stepping into it. If i stringify the data and console.log it, I can see that the data is IN tracking as shown in the first code snippet.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Just loop through you datas and your good to go

Comment: That was it. I just looped through it and it was there!

Answer (score 0):

Try returning a promise from the factory rather than using a callback:

```
getwaiting: function(){
        return $http.get('/pre-auth/getwaitingsubmit').then(function success(data){
            return data.data;
        })
    }
```

in controller

```
WaitingFactory.getwaiting().then(function(data){
        console.log(data.tracking);
        $scope.waitinglist = data;
    });
```

Small warning: When you expand the data object in the console view when `console.log` is called, it shows *the most recent* value of the  data object, i.e. when the asynchronous $http call returned valid data.

Try printing `data.tracking` instead, which should return `undefined` if this truly is an asynchronous problem. Please refer to: [Weird behavior with objects & console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429203/weird-behavior-with-objects-console-log)

Answer (score 0):

After trying Oberon's suggestion, the data was printed the same way.

I then noticed  t3__rry's comment to just "loop through it" and sure enough with an ng-repeat, the data WAS there I just needed to loop through it, I guess angularJS just didnt want to show the objects in the print.

Its still peculiar that in the chrome console it still showed tracking as Array[0].

Thank you all for the quick replies!!