# Why does this array return a length of 3 when it's clearly 4 elements?

Tags: javascript

Why does this array return a length of 3 when it's clearly 4 elements?

```
'matt'.split('').sort();
```

[image]

Comment: It looks as though it is showing t as a duplicate value.

Comment: @diskodave Can't reproduce

Comment: `'matt'.split('').sort().length;` returns 4 for me when I plug it straight  into the browser console.

Comment: It doesn't show the same for me. Chrome 54. Shows expected value of 4

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429203/weird-behavior-with-objects-console-log

Comment: Are you certain that it's the same variable?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you've run into the classic "the console doesn't log at runtime, it logs when you inspect the data structure" error. Check out [Weird behavior with objects & console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429203/weird-behavior-with-objects-console-log)

Basically, the value of the array is calculated when you click the spindown arrow. The small blue (i) next to the array (you can mouse over it) lets you know that the value displayed is the value at the time of clicking the structure open, not the value at the time you console.logged it.

Google "value below was evaluated just now" for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The following shows a length of 4.

```js
console.log('matt'.split('').sort().length);
```

Comment: You should put this demo inline using a code snippet.

Comment: @Soviut Done as you mentioned