# javascript object assign value not working as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays

Ive a function that Im having an assignment issue with.

It looks like this with the troubleshooting console.log statements:

```
function myfunc()
    {

  the_node = some_array; //with data.$color = #111111

    console.log('before: '+the_node.data["$color"]); //returns #111111
    console.log(the_node); //returns #111111 (at data.$color)

    the_node.data["$color"] = "#000000" ; //the assignment

    console.log('after: '+the_node.data["$color"]); //returns #000000
    console.log(the_node); //returns #111111 (should return #000000) (at data.$color)

  }
```

The interesting thing is that on the console I get the right values returned for before and after for the variable 'the_node.data.$color' showing the assignment has taken place but it has not been assigned within the object 'the_node'.

Any ideas why this is happening?

(below are the contents of the object 'the_node' with the object 'data')

```
$$family: "class"

Config: {$extend: false, overridable: true, type: "multipie", color: "#e6e6e6", alpha: 1, …}

Edge: {$extend: false, overridable: false, type: "none", color: "#ccb", lineWidth: 1, …}

Label: {$extend: false, overridable: true, type: "Native", style: " ", size: 10, …}

Node: {$extend: false, overridable: true, type: "multipie", color: "#e6e6e6", alpha: 1, …}

_angularWidth: 1

_depth: 1

_flag: true

_treeAngularWidth: 3.1666666666666665


angleSpan: {begin: 0, end: 2.7762911822421428}

constructor: function()

data: Object
$alpha: "1"
$color: "#87b13e"
$dim-quotient: 1
$label-size: 15
$span: 2.7762911822421428
class: "trait"
color: "#000000"
trait: "endurance"

Object Prototype
```

Comment: your code works as expected for me - can you make a runnable example

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue — http://jsbin.com/motezewihe/1/edit?js,output — or see any way that you could get the result you do. I could understand getting the results **the other way around** with the *new* value showing up before and after it was set and there are [duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429203/weird-behavior-with-objects-console-log) for that.

Comment: yes its quite strange .. makes no sense

Comment: can you provide the array (the_node) so that we can have a better understanding?

Comment: pls see obj explanation

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what the_node actually contains as the line:

```
     console.log(the_node); //returns #111111
```

Cannot be correct if the line above:

```
     console.log('before: '+the_node.data["$color"]); //returns #111111
```

Is correct?

Try:

```
    console.dir(the_node);
```

This will cause the full contents of the_node to be displayed including members.

Also type:

```
    console.log(typeof the_node);
```

To see if it is an object.

NOTE:  When prefixing any variable with $, if using jquery 'color' becomes an object with lots of additional functionality, you cannot then simply assign to $color, you should be assigning to something like $color.value or which ever part of the object you want to assign to.

Comment: the_node.data["$color"] is a string and  the_node is an object

Comment: ok, in your comment you assign an array to 'the_node', is 'some_array' actually an array or is it an object with a member called 'data' ?

Comment: yes thats correct - its an object with a member called data'

Comment: Which ?  Is it an array ?  Or it is an object with a member called 'data' ?

Comment: pls see clarified answer - object + member called data

Comment: Try dropping the '$' as if you have jquery included it will be overloaded.

Comment: when i do that it no longer assigns the value

Comment: All you should do is remove the $ replacing $color with color, do this in all cases.

Comment: Doh!  If $color is what you are trying to assign to then $color is not a string, but an object, you probably need to use $color.value, again try console.log(typeof the_node.data.$color);

Comment: In jquery syntax $ adds a bunch of functionality, so color becomes an object.