# jQuery Array Not Working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this simple array, but I cannot access the elements inside it. I have this ajax code in which I'm getting booked dates and storing them in an array. Then I'm just check if the selected date is booked or not by simple `inArray` but its not working. I have also tried getting the direct value but it gives me `undefined`.

**AJAX**

```
window.carRentalBookedOutDays = [];

var dataObj = {
    'action':'car_rental_booked_dates_request',
    'car_rental_id' : carRentalId,
    'month' : month,
    'year' : year,
    'nonce' : BYTAjax.nonce
};

$.ajax({
    url: BYTAjax.ajaxurl,
    data: dataObj,
    success:function(json) {
        // This outputs the result of the ajax request
        var bookedDates = JSON.parse(json);

        var i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < bookedDates.length; ++i) {
            window.carRentalBookedOutDays.push(bookedDates[i].booking_date);
        }

        if (typeof(callDelegate) !== 'undefined') {
            callDelegate();
        }
    },
    error: function(errorThrown) {

    }
});
```

**Checking Condition:**

```
var datesArray = window.carRentalBookedOutDays;
var dateToCheck = "2017-11-03";

console.log(datesArray);

// returns undefined
console.log(datesArray[0]);

if ($.inArray(dateToCheck, datesArray) > -1) {
    dateTest = false;
    break;
}
if ($.inArray(dateToCheck2, datesArray) > -1) {
    dateTest = false;
    break;
}
```

**Output:** http://take.ms/HRK76

Answer (score 0):

Something strange was happening, if I added a delay in the checking script it worked. But adding delay was not the right option.

I ended up verifying the dates in the ajax success method itself, it was working fine in there.

I think this issue is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429203/weird-behavior-with-objects-console-log)