# Vuex module not accessible from rootState

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vuex, vuex-modules

I needed to get route's query parameters inside Vuex in order to preload filter settings and update the state of the application. To make this possible I installed [vuex-router-sync](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex-router-sync).

Next step was to synchronize the Vuex and VueRouter.

Router:

```js
Vue.use(VueRouter);
export default new VueRouter({ mode: 'history' });
```

---

Store:

```js
Vue.use(Vuex);
export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: { filters: FiltersModule },
    plugins: [ FiltersPlugin ]
});
```

---

App's bootstrap:

```js
const unsync = sync(store, router);
new Vue({
    el: '#restaurant-admin-app',
    components: {
        'App': AppComponent,
        'filters': FilterComponent,
        'orders-table': OrdersTableComponent
    },
    store,
    router
});
```

---

My `FilterPlugin` that should trigger the URL parsing:

```js
export default store => {
    store.dispatch('filters/parseURLFilterSettings');
}
```

---

And now, the funny part, here's the URL parsing action:

```js
parseURLFilterSettings: ({ state, commit, rootState }) {
    console.log('RootState:',                rootState);
    console.log('Route module (incorrect):', rootState.route);
    console.log('Filters module (correct):', rootState.filters);
    console.log('Object\'s keys:',           Object.keys(rootState));
}
```

[image: Console log output]

What am I doing wrong? I thought it might be something with syncing, but at the end the console.log shows clearly that the route Object is there (and it's not empty), but somehow when I access it, it's `undefined`. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was very well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429203/weird-behavior-with-objects-console-log). What it basically says is that the object's value is evaluated when you open it's body in the console.

The problem was I didn't have the `route` module loaded yet, because I was trying to dispatch an action from a vuex plugin which seems to load before the `vuex-router-sync`'s syncing was done.

The problem was solved when I moved application's bootstrap logic from vuex plugins into the `AppRootComponent`'s mount lifecycle event.

Answer (score 0):

You should import the router-sync. After that your store and routes wil behave properly. I usually do this in the `main.js` file.

```
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import { sync } from 'vuex-router-sync'

sync(store, router)
```

Comment: It's, of course, imported. I just didn't want the question to have 2,000 lines because of imports. But, thanks.