# Javascript returning a sparse array from "push" operations despite the logged value having numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, backtracking

I'm working on my backtracking algorithim skills and I've run into a problem. The problem is to generate all permutations of an array of distinct integers i.e
permute([1,2,3]) => [[1,3,2], [1,2,3], [2,1,3], [2,3,1], [3,1,2], [3,2,1]]

I have the written like so:

```
var permute = function(nums) {
        var backtrack = function(nums, chosen, solutions) {
          if (chosen.length === nums.length) {
              // I'm not mutating nums.length so I don't get why this is pushing on empty arrays
              console.log(chosen); 
              solutions.push(chosen);
          } else {
              for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
                  if (!chosen.includes(nums[i])) {
                      chosen.push(nums[i]);
                      backtrack(nums, chosen, solutions);
                      chosen.pop();              
                  }
              }
          }
        }
        var chosen = [];
        var solutions = [];
        backtrack(nums, chosen, solutions);
        return solutions;
}
```

When I log out the `chosen` array variable on line 5, it has 4 values as I expect.  However, I noticed that Javascript claims it has 4 values but a length property of zero.  This means that when I run my function `permute([1,2,3])`, I get a result of `[[], [], [], [], [], []]` or nums.length factorial number of sparse arrays.  I suspect that my loop is the problem and I'm not fully understanding all these array references I'm passing around but I'm not sure what else to do. Logging out `chosen` is what I expect.  I appreciate any help or further readings.

This is not specific to the Chrome console environment. If I run this inside of a node repl I see the same behavior.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429203/weird-behavior-with-objects-console-log

Comment: I don't see any sparse arrays in your code, since you're always `push`ing. (that's a good thing, sparse arrays should never exist if you can avoid it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mutate the same array `chosen`. For pushing a result, you could add a copy of the `chosen` array.

```
solutions.push(chosen.slice());
```

The part

```
for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (!chosen.includes(nums[i])) {
        chosen.push(nums[i]);
        backtrack(nums, chosen, solutions);
        chosen.pop();
    }
}
```

iterates all elements of `nums` and checks if the value is already in `chosen`. If not, the value is pushed into the array `chosen`. Then the backtracking takes place and after this, the last value of `chosen` gets removed.

At the end, `chosen` is an empty array, which is the result of the pushing of the same array/object reference.

As result, you get the right amount of items (6), but always the same empty array.

```js
var permute = function(nums) {
        var backtrack = function(nums, chosen, solutions) {
          if (chosen.length === nums.length) {
              // I'm not mutating nums.length so I don't get why this is pushing on empty arrays
              //console.log(chosen); 
              solutions.push(chosen.slice());
          } else {
              for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
                  if (!chosen.includes(nums[i])) {
                      chosen.push(nums[i]);
                      backtrack(nums, chosen, solutions);
                      chosen.pop();              
                  }
              }
          }
        }
        var chosen = [];
        var solutions = [];
        backtrack(nums, chosen, solutions);
        return solutions;
}

console.log(permute([1, 2, 3]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well.  Can you explain a little more about why the original value of `chosen` [] was part of the solutions when the if block that compares array lengths would not run with it? i.e. [].length will never equal [1,2,3].length?