# Why does chrome consoles jquery added value to select options even before I assign a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have a select input where I am adding another option via `jQuery`, 
The steps I am following here is creating an `option` element by documents `createElement` method, then adding some `innerHTML`  and at last, setting the `value`.

The problem is at the second step, when I just created an element and added the `innerHTML` only ( didn't add the value yet ), chrome consoles the element with the `value` which I have added in the next step.

How does chrome do this ? and why ?

Check the code snippet below:

**Note:** The snippet here shows it corretly, but **chrome** browser **doesn't** when I am running the code from an individual `.html` file.
**Firefox** shows the correct output though.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#addSteve').on('click', function() {
    var newVal = document.createElement('option');
    newVal.text = 'Steve';
    console.log(newVal); // didn't assign a value 'hello', still consoles it;
    newVal.value = 'Hello';
    console.log(newVal); // supposed to console the value here only;

    $('#wrapper').find('select').append(newVal);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <select>
    <option value="John" selected>John</option>
    <option value="Nick">Nick</option>
    <option value="Gomez">Gomez</option>
  </select>
</div>

<button type="button" id="addSteve">Add Steve</button>
```

Comment: Please check the `Note` at the end of my question, the snippet works here, but not on an individual `.html` file

Comment: then its impossible to answer this question because the demo is not showing what the problem is

Comment: [`option`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) doesn't have HTML, it can contain plain text and escaped HTML characters only. Though some browsers shows a set innerHTML as option text, you can't rely all browsers rendering invalid markup correctly.

Comment: @Teemu how to put the text in the `option` then ?

Comment: `option.text` is the property to set.

Comment: @guradio there are a lot of questions that can't be demonstrate here because the snippet runs in an `iframe` ( I guess ), but in an individual `.html` file, it clearly does. if you want, I can share a link to some `gist`. Do you want me to ? Thanks

Comment: Do you see a small blue i-icon in Chrome console?. If you see it, please hover over the icon, and read the explanation.

Comment: @Teemu no, I don't see any icon like that, I updated my local `.html` file with `newVal.text` property, still seeing the same result

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23429304/1169519

Comment: @Teemu that does explain the reason in a bit, but is there any way to get the synchronous result / the expected one ?

Comment: In zzzzBov's answer that is mentioned: "_log the individual values_".

Comment: Another explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23392650/2159528)

Answer (score 1):

It takes approximately 8ms (at least on my computer, yours might be faster/slower) for the trace to output in Chrome, and so reflects the variable's value after those milliseconds. See:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#addSteve').on('click', function() {
    var newVal = document.createElement('option');
    newVal.text = 'Steve';
    console.log(newVal); 
    setTimeout(function(){
      newVal.value = 'Hello';
      console.log(newVal); 
    }, 8); // replace with a lower number see the value traced in the earlier console log.

    $('#wrapper').find('select').append(newVal);
  });
});
```