# Javascript node empty even before appending it's contents to a different node

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I'm creating a JQuery object(let's call it `$dummyHTML`) and setting some html content inside it. Then I go through each of it's child nodes including text ones, do some checks, and append them to a new different JQuery Object(let's call it $refinedHTML).

But the problem is that the contents of `$dummyHTML` seems to be empty even before I append them to `$refinedHTML`!

Now, I know that JQuery `append` function doesn't copy a node, it actually **transfers** the node to the other JQuery object. So I'm guessing the `append` function triggers before I mean it to?

Here is a minified example of the issue.

```js
var $dummyHTML = $('<div/>');
$dummyHTML.html('Hello there, <span>myself!</span>');

var $refinedHTML = $('<div/>');

console.log($dummyHTML[0]);
$dummyHTML.contents().each(function() {
 $refinedHTML.append($(this));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But if I remove the `.contents` part the programs works as expected.

Comment: "_append function triggers before I mean it to?_" Nope, the console log fires later than you think it would.

Comment: The console is asynchronous. If you logged the actual value instead of the reference (`console.log($dummyHTML[0].innerHTML);` you'd see the correct value. When you're logging a reference, the content of the element changes before the object properties are actually listed to the the console, hence the missleading results.

Comment: @Teemu this deserves to be wrote as answer, kindly do.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy This is more like a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429203/weird-behavior-with-objects-console-log

Comment: @Teemu but your answer is intuitive than the answers in the link you mentioned ^^

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy I don't know, I find zzzzBov's answer in that post even more intuitive as my comment ...

Comment: @Teemu I won't keep on arguing, but it's all a matter of preference in understanding :) Happy New Year!

Answer (score 0):

`.contents()` extracts the content of a **DOM element** .When you create an object on the fly,it is not yet a DOM element so `.contents()` will not work however you can manipulate the object data in other ways.

Reference [here](https://api.jquery.com/contents/):

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .contents() method allows us to search through the immediate children of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching elements.