# How to fix "No Array Name In The Output"

Tags: javascript, arrays

Noob to javascript and when i tried adding element to an array, the output was something like this:

```
var shit = ["r", "t", "y"]
shit.unshift("q");
shit;
Array(4) [ "q", "r", "t", "y" ]
```

Where is was looking for this:

```
var shit = ["r", "t", "y"]
shit.unshift("q");
shit;
[ "q", "r", "t", "y" ]
```

Comment: Sorry, what's the question?

Comment: The output is printing "array(4)" before the expected result.

Comment: It would help if you would tell us where you are using this javascript. Not in a webpage, I guess, because on a webpage this doesn't output shit (pun intended).

Comment: That's just how your console shows arrays (the output type is an array). If you convert it to a string, it would be displayed without that. That text in the output doesn't change the fact that it's the correct array though, and you can perform your expected operations on that.

Comment: oh no man, just messing around. Btw, its in blank page's console.

Comment: Ah in the console. What would you care if it outputs that in the console? It is only for debugging purposes!

Context matters a LOT if you want answers, so I am glad you cleared that up.

Answer (score 2):

The `Array(4)` before the `[...]` in the console is just the console telling you that the object being logged is an array of length 4. It doesn't mean anything else; you're still free to manipulate the array as you want without problems - it's not like it's actually become a string or anything strange like that..

I suppose if you really wanted not to see the `Array(..)` before the items, you could use `JSON.stringify` when you log it:

```js
var arr = ["r", "t", "y"]
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

(though, note that passing an object to `console.log` will show you the *live object*, whereas stringifying it will show you the object *at the moment it was logged* - see [Weird behavior with objects & console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429203/weird-behavior-with-objects-console-log) )

Answer (score 0):

If that code is inside a function, you can

```
return shit;
```

Or maybe if you want to print it in the console, you can

```
console.log(shit);
```

But if you are just executing that in the browser console, I think there is no way to obtain the result you are looking for.

Comment: No mate, it doesn't work. The JSON stringify method works. Thanks anyway.