# Why is this data showing undefined when there are clearly values?

Tags: javascript, json

On my page, I'm logging this:

```
console.log(self);
console.log(self.data.events);
```

The `self` is showing data, however `self.data.events` is showing `undefined`, how am I referencing this wrong?

[image]

Comment: does `console.log(self.data)` work?

Comment: I placed a debug point at line 110 and see that data in self is an empty object. But when I am running without the debug point. I see data object I guess the point at which you are trying to access data is not yet updated but going further it's updated asynchronously somewhere else.

Comment: @NickParsons yes it does: https://i.imgur.com/Te2tz5S.png

Comment: @DineshKumar but why is `console.log(self.data)` working but not `console.log(self.data.events)`?

Comment: @sojim2 you may be having the issue described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429203/weird-behavior-with-objects-console-log

Comment: It's just me or `data` does not contain a json map?

Comment: @sojim2 That's what I am saying It's updating it asynchronously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but why is console.log(self.data) working but not console.log(self.data.events)?

As @Nick Parsons hinted in his comment, it might be because `console.log` behaves asynchronously in some browsers and will not log a "snapshot" at the time it was logged but will reflect updates on whatever is referenced, in this case `self.data` (which is initially defined as an empty object!)...

I have a feeling that @Dinesh Kumar's comment is on the right track, you're calling these functions after each other:

```js
self.load_event_data();
self.load_zip_codes();
self.bind_events();
self.handle_filter_params();
self.cluster();
```

the issue is within `self.cluster()` but it is possible that the AJAX call you're making in `self.load_event_data()` is not be done yet when `self.cluster()` is called, so I'd suggest you try and call `self.cluster()` from within `self.load_event_data()` whenever you got data updated with the events.

Comment: It seems like no matter where I put `self.cluster();` it shows undefined, this must mean the `xhr` itself is asynchronous and only loads when it's done, I tried even at the end of the script and it still shows `undefined` very strange. I've added `self.cluster();` to line `280` now and still no luck.

Comment: looks like `setTimeout(function() {self.cluster()}, 1000);` somewhat , works but causing other errors still.

Comment: Looks like I needed to put the self.cluster() in the xhr callback section for it to complete. Though it didn't specifically resolved the issue, it did point me to the right direction. Thanks for that.