# Same result on logging the state after render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

**I understand that useState is asynchronous. Please read the full question before answering.**

I'm trying to modify an element in an array with `useState` but it doesn't work as expected.

The array and the function to modify it:

```
const [table, setTable] = useState(['blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue']);

let currentShapePosition = 2;

function printTable() {
  let newTable = [...table];
  // let newTable = table;
  newTable[currentShapePosition] = 'red';
  setTable(newTable);
  console.log('printTable newTable', newTable); // <-- the result is as expected
  // log => printTable newTable ["blue", "blue", "red", "blue", "blue"]
  console.log('printTable table', table); // <--- The problem is here. I don't get why the array never update
  // log => printTable newTable ["blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue"]
}
```

Because `useState` is asynchronous, I understand that the array may not change immediately, but, inside the `printTable` function the `console.log` **result is the same even after several re-renders**.

When instead of:
`let newTable = [...table]`

I do this : `let newTable = table`

Then the state is updated inside the console.log generated in the function but then there is no re-rendering/component update.

**I would like to understand why** in the first case `newTable = [...table]` inside the function the console.log result is the same after several re-renders.
**And why** in the second case `newTable = table` there is no re-rendering of the component despite `setTable(newTable)`.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./style.css";

const App = () => {
  let currentShapePosition = 2;

  const [table, setTable] = useState(["blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue"]);

  useEffect(() => {
    printTable();
    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress);
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("render", table);
  });

  function printTable() {
    let newTable = [...table];
    // let newTable = table;
    newTable[currentShapePosition] = "red";
    setTable(newTable);
    console.log("printTable newTable", newTable); // <-- the result is as expected
    console.log("printTable table", table); // <--- The problem is here. I don't get why the initial value never change
  }

  function handleKeyPress(event) {
    switch (event.key) {
      case "Left": // IE/Edge specific value
      case "ArrowLeft":
        moveShape(-1);
        break;
      case "Right": // IE/Edge specific value
      case "ArrowRight":
        moveShape(1);
        break;
      default:
        return;
    }
  }

  function moveShape(direction) {
    currentShapePosition += direction;
    printTable();
  }

  return (
    <table className="tetris-table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td className={table[0]} />
          <td className={table[1]} />
          <td className={table[2]} />
          <td className={table[3]} />
          <td className={table[4]} />
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

const root = document.getElementById("root");

ReactDOM.render(<App />, root);
```

[image: Edit fervent-field-787ky]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why calling react setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Comment: Its not duplicate, people please read the question

Comment: If it's not a dupe, it's a missing [mcve]...

Comment: It has an example in code-sandbox, I believe it happens because of closures but I admit I'm not 100% with it.

Comment: And even your codesandbox seems to work as expected...

Comment: @DennisVash codesandbox doesn't qualify for a valid [mcve]. Anything relevant should be in the question description itself.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I'll edit his question, you should upvoted it, his example **doesn't** work, you can see the `printTable table` always shows the same value

Comment: My full code is a tetris. I'm trying to reduce it as much as I can and I admit that I'm not perfectly clear but it's really difficult to define clearly a problem that I do not understand.

Comment: Also possibly related to [objects in the console being evaluated asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23429203/1218980). But either way, I'm seeing the right values when I look in the console.

Comment: I see these values in the console:printTable newTable 
["blue", "blue", "red", "blue", "blue"]

printTable table 
["blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue"]

render 
["blue", "blue", "red", "blue", "blue"] and I think that in the second case it should not be always "blue".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your first `useEffect`, because you removed the `eslint` warning, it hidden a potential bug.

```
useEffect(() => {
  printTable();
  window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress);
  //   v hidden bug, you should consider the warnings
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, []);
```

What happened here, is that on **component mount** the **first** instance of `handleKeyPress` assigned to `addEventListener` (refer to [`closures`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)), where all array was of value "blue" and it will keep it that way until the unmount.

You should be aware that **on every render** the component body executed, therefore in your case, there is a new instance of every function.

The same goes for `currentPosition` that should be a reference.

To fix it, remove the `eslint` comment and go with the warnings:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const printTable = () => {
    let newTable = [...table];
    newTable[currentPosition.current] = 'red';
    setTable(newTable);
    console.log('closure', table);
  };

  function handleKeyPress(event) {
    switch (event.key) {
      case 'Left': // IE/Edge specific value
      case 'ArrowLeft':
        moveShape(-1);
        break;
      case 'Right': // IE/Edge specific value
      case 'ArrowRight':
        moveShape(1);
        break;
      default:
        return;
    }
  }

  function moveShape(direction) {
    currentPosition.current += direction;
    printTable();
  }

  window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress);

  return () => window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress);
}, [table]);
```

[image: Edit Q-58329134-LogTable]

Comment: Yes maybe. I have read a little about closures before asking my question but the way closures work is not very clear to me at the moment.

Comment: I found the bug, it was thought one, feel free accepting the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: The only thing missing now is the return value of the `useEffect` hook, which should be a function that removes the key event.

Comment: `return () => window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress);`

Comment: Thanks, also there should be a reference for `currentPosition` because of the same reasons

Answer (score 1):

**Variables created with React methods are special objects with special behaviour ;)**

Your function refers to the variable `table` which is a special React ("state") object. Looks, in such a case, the function always gets the initial state of the variable - otherwise it would show different values at least with the next renders.

If you use a regular table as a variable you will get what is expected. I think this changed version of your code demonstrates that quite well:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./style.css";

const App = () => {
  let currentShapePosition = 2;

  let tableDemo = ["blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue"];
  function setTableDemo(newTable) {
    tableDemo = newTable.slice();
    setTable(tableDemo); // used to trigger rendering
  }

  // for rendering purposes (to keep the original code structure)
  const [table, setTable] = useState(tableDemo);

  useEffect(() => {
    printTable();
    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress);
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("render", table);
  });

  function printTable() {
    let newTable = [...table];
    // let newTable = table;
    newTable[currentShapePosition] = "red";
    setTableDemo(newTable);
    console.log("printTable newTable", newTable); // <-- the result is as expected
    console.log("printTable tableDemo", tableDemo); // <--- The problem is here. I don't get why the initial value never change
  }

  function handleKeyPress(event) {
    switch (event.key) {
      case "Left": // IE/Edge specific value
      case "ArrowLeft":
        moveShape(-1);
        break;
      case "Right": // IE/Edge specific value
      case "ArrowRight":
        moveShape(1);
        break;
      default:
        return;
    }
  }

  function moveShape(direction) {
    currentShapePosition += direction;
    printTable();
  }

  return (
    <table className="tetris-table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td className={table[0]} />
          <td className={table[1]} />
          <td className={table[2]} />
          <td className={table[3]} />
          <td className={table[4]} />
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

const root = document.getElementById("root");

ReactDOM.render(<App />, root);
```

**Use React "state" objects only to keep "source state values"**

Basically it's best to use React "state" objects only to keep "source state values", used to trigger re-rendering. In this specific case the source state value is `currentShapePosition`. The table as such should not change - only some specific elements of this table. So actually the code, according to React approach, could look like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./style.css";

const App = () => {
  const [currentPosition, setPosition] = useState(2);
  const table = useRef(["blue", "blue", "red", "blue", "blue"]);

  function handleKeyPress(event) {
    let newPosition;

    console.log("currentPosition:", currentPosition);
    table.current[currentPosition] = "blue";
    switch (event.key) {
      case "Left": // IE/Edge specific value
      case "ArrowLeft":
        newPosition = currentPosition - 1;
        break;
      case "Right": // IE/Edge specific value
      case "ArrowRight":
        newPosition = currentPosition + 1;
        break;
      default:
    }
    table.current[newPosition] = "red";
    console.log("newPosition:", newPosition);
    console.log("table:", table.current);
    // trigger the new render
    setPosition(newPosition);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress);
  });

  return (
    <table className="tetris-table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td className={table.current[0]} />
          <td className={table.current[1]} />
          <td className={table.current[2]} />
          <td className={table.current[3]} />
          <td className={table.current[4]} />
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

const root = document.getElementById("root");

ReactDOM.render(<App />, root);
```

Of course, the best solution is to render dynamically the `<td>` elements, with relevant class, without any table. But it's a different story, beyond this question.

Answer (score 0):

useState calls are asynchronous, they don't update directly.
refer : https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Read more in this answer : [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Comment: I do understand that useState is asynchronous so the array may not change immediately, but, inside the printTable function the console.log result is the same even after several re-renders.
Actually, even after the component update, for exemple with a useEffect, inside the print table function the console.log result is the same.

Comment: Please read the question, I downvoted because it doesn't answer it.