# Object has values but says size is 0 javascript

Tags: javascript

I create an object and add properties and values to it. However, when I try to iterate through the keys it says I have a size of 0.

```
let hash = {};

this.props.user.user.following.forEach(async topicId => {
    await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(queries.getTopic, {id: topicId})).then(data => {
    if(data) {
        const tweetId = data.data.getTopic.post.id;
        if(!hash[tweetId]){
            let post = data.data.getTopic.post;
            post.topics = [{
                id: data.data.getTopic.id,
                name: data.data.getTopic.name
            }]
            hash[tweetId] = post;
        } else {
            console.log("Found tweet. Appending to topics array.");
            let post = hash[tweetId];
            let topicsArr = post.topics;
            topicsArr.push({
                id: data.data.getTopic.id,
                name: data.data.getTopic.name
            })
            post.topics = topicsArr;
            hash[tweetId] = post;
        }
    }})
});

console.log("Hash: ", hash);
console.log("Map size: ", Object.keys(hash).length);
let tweets = [];
for(var key in hash) {
    tweets.push(hash[key]);
}
console.log("Tweets to go into state: ", tweets);
```

My output is as follows(the array on the last line is empty):

[image: Output]

Comment: Is that the actual code, seems not possible with what is provided.

Comment: I omitted the for-loop to add the other object which is shown in the console. However the problem still applies regardless.

Comment: If possible, please provide full example of the code (cause this is not working)

Comment: that blue [i] in the console is telling me no.... it is not the same code. Change the line `console.log("Hash: ", hash);` to `console.log("Hash: ", JSON.stringify(hash));`

Comment: What do you see if you put in a breakpoint and step through? Does anything weird happen (or, more importantly, **not** happen) when this runs?

Comment: Your object is empty when you log it and its size. It will  be not empty after the promise resolves. That is why you can expand it in the browser console with its final properties.

Comment: You can see it if you try to change your first log to `console.log("Hash: ", JSON.stringify(hash));`

Comment: @giuseppedeponte you are right it shows empty when I do `console.log("Hash: ", JSON.stringify(hash))` How do I wait for the promise to resolve? Doesn't it already wait since I put `await` in front of my async call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're adding to the `hash` object with an **async** function.

So, each of runs through the `forEach` are done asynchronously, and the evaluation of the rest of the code continues on. The block where you use the data runs *before* your asynchronous functions have all completed.

You should have both the code where you fetch *and* the code where you process data from an API call in the same asynchronous block, since, when you think about it, a block of code can't depend on asynchronous code without *itself* being asynchronous.

You probably want to await all of the API calls you're doing in that loop. To do so, you can use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

```js
const tweets = async () => {
  let hash = {};

  await Promise.all(this.props.user.user.following.map(async topicID => {
    const data = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(queries.getTopic, { id: topicID }));
    // No need to use .then(), since we're awaiting anyways
    if (data) {
      const tweedID = data.data.getTopic.post.id;
      if (!hash[tweetID]) {
        let post = data.data.getTopic.post;
        post.topics = [{
          id: data.data.getTopic.id,
          name: data.data.getTopic.name
        }]
        hash[tweedID] = post;
      } else {
        console.log("Found tweet. Appending to topics array.");
        let post = hash[tweedID];
        let topicsArr = post.topics;
        topicsArr.push({
          id: data.data.getTopic.id,
          name: data.data.getTopic.name
        });
        post.topics = topicsArr;
        hash[tweedID] = post;
      }
    }
  }));

  console.log("Hash: ", hash);
  console.log("Map size: ", Object.keys(hash).length);
  let tweets = [];
  for (const key in hash) {
    tweets.push(hash[key]);
  }
  console.log("Tweets to go into state: ", tweets);
}

tweets();

// Or, put the whole thing in brackets and call it immediately:
(async () => {
  // ...
})();
```

---

The reason that you see that the logged object has values is because of a feature of the dev-console that live-refreshes objects' properties, so they will no longer reflect the state when they've been logged, but instead display their current value.

Consider the following example:

```js
const obj = {};
console.log(obj);
obj.foo = 'bar';
```

You'll see that the `obj`'s `foo` property is `'bar'`, even though it was `undefined` when `console.log` was actually run. As [@epascarello](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14104/epascarello) pointed out in the comments, you can tell when your browser has done this because of the little blue `[i]`. If you hover over it, you'll see that it says "This value was evaluated **just now**".

To avoid that behavior, `JSON.stringify` the object before logging:

```js
const obj = {}
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
obj.foo = 'bar'
```

This will log `{}`, as you might expect, since it turns it into a string and spits that text out, instead of a reference to `obj`.

See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429203/weird-behavior-with-objects-console-log).

Comment: JavaScript code (except workers) runs on the main thread. And async code also runs in the main thread. While we are "awaiting", code bellow is not executing.