# Javascript how to load contents from multiple json files using FileReader.onload?

Tags: javascript, json, filereader, onload

I need to upload multiple json files and store their contents in an array. My goal is to somehow merge them together. I tried doing this:

```
var results = new Array();    //global variable

document.getElementById('uploadId').onclick = function () {
   var files = document.getElementById('selectFiles').files;

   for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
       var fr = new FileReader();

       fr.onload = function (e) {
           console.log(e);
           var result = JSON.parse(e.target.result);
           results.push(result);
       }

       fr.readAsText(files.item(i));
   }
   process();
}; 

function process(){
   console.log(results); // displays everything as expected
   console.log(results.length); // returns 0 ?!
   console.log(results[0]) // return undefined ?!
}
```

then while logging the `results` array into console, everything displays as expected. But when I try to iterate through the array, all the individual objects are `undefined`. And `results.length` returns `0` as well.

I guess there might be a problem connected to the asynchronicity. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Does there happen to be a little blue '`i`' symbol next to `results` when it gets logged?

Comment: @matthew-e-brown yeah, it does

Comment: That little '`i`' is the browser's console telling you that that piece of data was evaluated when you went to look at in the console, and **not** when its line was reached. This means that (probably) it was empty while `process()` was running, and it wasn't until afterwards when you inspected that it was actually populated.

Comment: @matthew-e-brown so I need to wait a bit before calling process() until the adding to the array is done?

Comment: You need to execute `process()` once all `fr.onload()` are finished.

Comment: Perhaps you should also be using `onchange` instead of `onclick`.

Comment: @Lain any tips on how to do that? onload is asynchronous, right?

Comment: You can bind a predefined object to the load function (or define a scope and/or global variable) which stores two values: filesToProcess and filesProcessed. On each onload you increment filesProcessed until it reaches filesToProcess.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind a predefined object to the load function (or define a scope and/or global variable) which stores two values: filesToProcess and filesProcessed. On each onload you increment filesProcessed until it reaches filesToProcess. This is, if you want to keep old browser like IE or old Safari versions supported.

Sadly I can only show it in theory, without any actual testing.

```
document.getElementById('uploadId').onclick = function () {
   var files = document.getElementById('selectFiles').files,
       param = {filesProcessed: 0, filesToProcess: files.length};

   for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
       var fr = new FileReader();

       fr.onload = function(e){
           results.push(JSON.parse(e.target.result));

           //REM: this being param
           this.filesProcessed++;

           if(this.filesProcessed === this.filesToProcess){
               process()
           }
       }.bind(param)

       fr.readAsText(files.item(i));
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would avoid this problem by making the code you're waiting for the files for (in this case, `process`) a part of the `FileReader`'s listener, so that it happens once it is finished. I can't think of a scenario when you would need to have the user upload multiple files to the same `input` and not be able to process them separately (i.e., if you needed two files to go hand-in-hand, take them in separate `input`s and use a submit button).

However, if you ever do, my advice would be to use `async`/`await` or ES6 Promises. Here is my approach to read all files into an array as JSON, and **then** do something with them.

```js
const results = [];
const input = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');

input.addEventListener('change', async() => {
  await Promise.all([...input.files].map(file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      try {
        resolve(results.push(JSON.parse(reader.result)));
      } catch (err) {
        // Return a blank value; ignore non-JSON (or do whatever else)
        console.log('Please use .json!');
        resolve();
      }
    }
    reader.readAsText(file);
  })));

  // Do Stuff
  console.log(results);
  console.log(results.length);
  console.log(results[0]);
});
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="file" multiple />
</form>
```

---

This is very similar to my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58963350/10549827).

Some JSON files to test:

```
[
  {
    "name": "bobby",
    "age": 12
  },
  {
    "name": "don",
    "age": 64
  },
  {
    "name": "dale",
    "age": 16
  },
  {
    "name": "toby",
    "age": 52
  },
  {
    "name": "alfred",
    "age": 234
  },{
    "name": "steve",
    "age": 12
  }
]
```

```
[
  {
    "name": "denmark"
  },
  {
    "name": "sweden"
  },
  {
    "name": "norway"
  },
  {
    "name": "finland"
  }
]
```

Comment: @pelikann Just keep in mind that when using Promises / Async & Await that you lose IE support. Don’t forget to pick an answer as accepted if it solved your problem! :)

Comment: One lame solution also came to my mind. I could just wrap process() into setTimeout of like 5s, and I guess it would work in most cases.

Comment: @pelikann you could most certainly, but I think that saying most would frown upon such a solution is an understatement ;)