# For empty object giving the TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, is-empty

Well, I know this is would be a very common question but I tried to find the solution but no luck yet. So here is the problem statement :

Due to some condition, my object is having no values and it is empty `{}` and when I try to check the length of this object using `Object.keys(ambassador).length` OR `Object.entries(ambassador).length` it is giving me the error

> TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object.

Code sample:

```
const ambassador = Array.isArray(ambassadors) 
        ? ambassadors.find((item) => {
                return item.affiliate_id === affiliate.tracking_id;
            })
        : {};

console.log(ambassador == null); //false
console.log(typeof(ambassador)); // Object
console.log(Object.keys(ambassador).length > 0 ); //TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object.
```

Comment: Note that `typeof null` gives `"object"`, `ambassador` is most likely `null`. Please show where you assign `ambassador`

Comment: @NickParsons ambassador == null is giving false, Updated the question

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log(JSON.stringify(ambassador))` above using `Object.keys()`?

Comment: @NickParsons updated the code.

Comment: @NickParsons it is giving me undefined

Comment: It might be possible that the output you're seeing in the console isn't the actual state of what you print (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429203/weird-behavior-with-objects-console-log)). Also, `.find()` will return `undefined` if it doesn't find anything. Maybe try `... ? amassadors.find(...) || {} : {};`

Comment: Tried ```... ? amassadors.find(...) || {} : {};``` but no luck, giving same error

Comment: Can you include `ambassadors` in your question?

Comment: you can use lodash _.isEmpty for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I got solution from the comment of Kireeti Ganisetti, He suggested to use LOADASH and it worked :)

To check if the object is empty in Javascript - React :

```
import _ from 'lodash';
_.isEmpty(ambassador)
```

Answer (score 0):

[As mdn says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null):

> The value null represents the intentional absence of any object value.
>   It is one of JavaScript's **primitive values** and is treated as falsy for
>   boolean operations

Try to check your object whether it is not `null` before reading keys:

```
let ambassador = null;
console.log(ambassador == null); //false
console.log(typeof(ambassador)); // Object
if (ambassador)
    console.log(Object.keys(ambassador).length > 0 );
```

An example:

```js
let ambassador = null;
console.log(ambassador == null); //false
console.log(typeof(ambassador)); // Object
if (ambassador)
    console.log(Object.keys(ambassador).length > 0 );
```

**UPDATE:**

If `let ambassador = {};` then `abmassador` is `truthy` so you can check keys of the object:

```
let ambassador = {};
console.log(ambassador == null); //false
console.log(typeof(ambassador)); // Object
if (ambassador)
    console.log(`ambassador`, Object.keys(ambassador).length > 0 );
```

[As mdn says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy):

> In JavaScript, a truthy value is a value that is considered true when
>   encountered in a Boolean context. All values are truthy unless they
>   are defined as falsy (i.e., except for false, 0, 0n, "", null,
>   undefined, and NaN).

Examples of truthy values in JavaScript (which will be coerced to true in boolean contexts, and thus execute the if block):

```
if (true)
if ({})
if ([])
if (42)
if ("0")
```

Comment: let ambassador is not ```null``` it is empty object ```{}```