# Attribute is defined in console, but not accessible in code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

At a loss here. I've got a React component and some data. My attribute is inaccessible in the code but can be accessed in the console from the same console.log.

Any idea what causes this bug?

I've attached screenshots:

[image: react code]
[image: console]

Comment: Could you share the all the code in the file and highlight where you are not able to access the variable?

Comment: As @T.Short said, having a decent snippet would be handful, are you sure you're trying to access the property on the right part of the React lifecycle?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Weird behavior with objects & console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429203/weird-behavior-with-objects-console-log)

Comment: It's probably that @EmileBergeron, but I'd love to get it working still. The console logging is done in the render method, which should update based on the attribute.

Comment: Like others have mentioned, we need a [mcve] to help.

Comment: Another behavior that can be observed without any debugging is the component updating based on the attribute, then it somehow updates again which removes the attribute. But it's constantly logged as undefined in the console.

Comment: I'll get a reproducible example up tomorrow.