# console.log(object) shows property and its value, but that property is not actually a key?

Tags: javascript, object, react-redux, object-properties

I have an object with multiple properties, one of which is 'lane' with a value of 1. `console.log(myObject)`, shows the property and its value are there. However, if I try to access it `myObject.lane`, it is'undefined'. Also - if I  print the keys of the object with `Object.keys(myObject)`, the array has all of the properties EXCEPT 
"lane"! I really don't know what else to do, or what kind of problem could cause this.

```
//actual code (in a React Redux reducer... which shouldn't matter in my opinion)
      console.group("What is happening?");
      console.log("myObject", myObject);
      console.log(
        "you can clearly see that 'lane' in is myObject with value of number 1."
      );
      console.log("Object.keys(myObject)", Object.keys(myObject));
      console.log("But somehow, 'lane' is not a key in myObject");
      console.log("MyObject again", myObject);
      console.log("myObject.lane is undefined? : ", myObject.lane);
      console.log("Other keys work, like myObject.alpha : ", myObject.alpha);
      console.groupEnd();
```

Here is a picture of the output of the console.

[image]

**What can cause an object to console.log a property and its value, but not actually be a key?**

Comment: you should share how ***you*** create the object, especially the `lane`

Comment: I can *guess* it's because `lane` is actually not exist at that moment. Note that `console.log` does not create a deep copy of the object.

Comment: The console doesn't print a snapshot of the value you're logging, but rather it prints a reference to the object. To print the current value see what `console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject))` gives

Comment: ..would you think it doesn't exist in that moment? but still shows up right before and right after with console.log(myObject)?

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject)) shows that the property is actually not there. Thanks!

Comment: @NicoWheat no worries, you can see this question for more details: [Weird behavior with objects & console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23429203) about console.log