# Electron wierd console.log value

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, console.log

I have something weird on the console.log in the Electron app, so basically it was the same as chromium does right?

Here's my code

```
let arr = [{
    actual_mix_class: 12,
    batch_id: "23498235025013",
    date: 1595416034349,
    days: [7, 7, 7, 14, 15, 28]
}]

let homeData = []

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].days.length; j++) {
    homeData[homeData.length] = arr[i]
    console.log(arr[i].days[j])
    homeData[homeData.length - 1].test_day = arr[i].days[j]
    console.log(homeData[homeData.length - 1])
    console.log(homeData[homeData.length - 1].test_day)
  }
}
```

I tried to separate days property into new arrays that has whole data inside object.

When I do console.log on **test_day** it was something not right on the display
[image]

It displayed correct it was **14** until I expanded the console.log then displayed **28**, and all **test_day** has same value **28**.

Then finally I do console at the end after process finish

```
homeData.forEach(e => {
  console.log(e.test_day)
})
```

It said **28** six times.

Where I doing wrong here? Please help, thank you in advanced.

Comment: See: [Weird behavior with objects & console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23429203)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you do `homeData[homeData.length] = arr[i]`, you are actually assigning a reference of the original `arr[i]` to the `homeData[homeData.length]`.

Then when you do `homeData[homeData.length - 1].test_day = arr[i].days[j]`, you are again assigning a reference to an internal property of the above object to another field of the same object, making it a circular reference.

What you can do is to use [**spread syntax**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to make a copy of the `arr[i]`, before assigning it to `homeData[homeData.length]` as below.

```
homeData[homeData.length] = {...arr[i]};
```

In case you are not using ES6, you can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) as below.

```
Object.assign(newObj, arr[i]);
homeData[homeData.length] = newObj;
```