# Cannot parse JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have following JSON:

```
[
   {
      "_id":"1",
      "a":"a",
      "b":"b",
      "c":"c",
      "__v":0
   },
   {
      "_id":"2",
      "d":"d",
      "e":"e",
      "f":"f",
      "__v":0
   }
]
```

If I do

```
console.log(myjson[0].a)
```

> And I`m getting following error: TypeError: undefined is not an object
> (evaluating 'myjson[0].a')

If I do

```
console.log(myjson)
```

Then I get

> [Object, Object]

How can I get the data from that JSON?

Comment: Your need to parse the JSON first using `JSON.parse(myjson)`.

Comment: This is probably a synchronicty problem. Show where you get the json and where you try to access the objects?

Comment: @Yousaf It would log as string not array of objects if it wasn't already parsed

Comment: @esea123 Please post the full snippet of your code where you retrieve the json and then where you should use the json retrieved. It will help us a lot.

Comment: Probably related [Weird behavior with objects & console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429203/weird-behavior-with-objects-console-log)

Comment: If I use JSON.parse, then I`m getting following error: **SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "object"**

Comment: Why didn't you log myjson[0]?

Comment: Result is same.. **TypeError: undefined is not an object**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. All I had to do was just a make a clone of that object.

```
let note = Object.assign({}, this.props.data.notesData);
```

And then

```
console.log(note[0].a);
```