# When console.log is executed?

Tags: javascript

I changed the attribute of the Node after printing it by "console.log" as you can see below.

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
<script>
    const h1 = document.querySelector('h1');
    console.log(h1);
    h1.style.color = 'red';
</script>
```

When I look at the console panel in devtool, I can see the log like below.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIWyV.png)

My question is why 'style="color: red"' seems to be applied in console? Even it's before applying by the next line of the "console.log".

Comment: I bet it's due to something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429203/weird-behavior-with-objects-console-log

Comment: Try opening your console and running `document.querySelector('h1').style.color = '#123456';` after your console log and you will understand the behavior.

Comment: Console objects are not snapshots...they are live objects that will display modifications made after you log them