# looping over ajax call to exit when the variable is "No" in javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have been working for the last two days and struggling to find a solution. Would be helpful if someone helps me. I am using nodejs and Vue.

- How should i come out from the ajax call when I get "No" result and need to stop the loop.
- Not able to access the `userExist` array variable.
- Also the same for when i converted to `this.info['isthisUser']` Vue variable.+

```
var thisUser = ["NY","NJ","CT","CA"]

var userExist = mycheck(thisUser)
console.log(userExist);

this.info['isthisUser'] = userExist;
console.log(this.info['isthisUser']);    

function mycheck(val) { 
    var usCNT = val.length; 
    var array = new Array();

    if (usCNT>0) {
        for (var u=0; u<usCNT; u++) {
        var checkThisUser = val[u];
            $.ajax
            ({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/getStates',
            data: { user: checkThisUser,},
            success: function (data, msg) {
            result = data ; 
            array.push(result);
            if(result === 'No') {
                alert('not exist');
                }
            })
        }
    }   
    return array;
};
```

`console.log(userExist)` shows this format

```
[]
0: "No"
1: "No"
2: "No"
3: "Yes"
length: 4
__ob__: Observer {value: Array(4), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
__proto__: Array
```

`console.log(this.info['isthisUser'])` shows the below

```
[__ob__: Observer]
0: "No"
1: "No"
2: "No"
3: "Yes"
length: 4
__ob__: Observer {value: Array(4), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
__proto__: Array
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Well you are making a bunch of asynchronous calls so all of them have been started.... loop os probably done before you are trying to cancel it.

Comment: ajax is async. meaning all the calls have been made long before the response of one of them came back

Comment: Your `console.log()`'s [are deceiving you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429203/weird-behavior-with-objects-console-log). At the point you are logging them, your arrays are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is obsolete, also `$.ajax` requests are performed in parallel, so exiting early from a loop won't prevent them from being completed, unless they are explicitly [aborted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery).

In case requests should be performed sequentially, a straightforward way to do this is `async..await`. `$.ajax` is able to return a promise:

```
async function mycheck(val) { 
    ...
    var array = [];
    for (var u=0; u<usCNT; u++) {
        var result = await $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: '/getStates',
          data: { user: checkThisUser,}
        });
        if (result === 'No') {
            throw new Error('not exist');
        }
        array.push(result);
    }
    return array;
};
```

The use of promises requires to consistently use them, either with `async..await` or plain `then` and `catch`. Since `mycheck` is able to return rejected promise on `throw`, an error should be handled in a caller.

If the intention of this function is to return a boolean, it can be simplified to:

```
    ...
    for (var u=0; u<usCNT; u++) {
        var result = await $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: '/getStates',
          data: { user: checkThisUser,}
        });
        if (result === 'No') {
           return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Estus Flask. Will try your suggestion.

Comment: Estus Flask, I get the below code for console.log(userExist);                         
  Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: false    - is it possible to get the value of PromiseResult?      if i can access this value from PromiseResult then my three days of my issue is resolved.

Comment: This was also explained in suggested question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call . This object is a *promise* of a result. You can't get the result from it because the result isn't available at this moment.

Comment: A caller should involve promises too because the whole process is asynchronous. It should either be `async` and contain `try { let result = await mycheck(thisUser) ... } catch (err) {...}`. Or use raw promises and contain `mycheck(thisUser).then(result => ...).catch(...)`. It should handle errors because they can happen. These two snippets are equivalent, but if you use transpilation and don't have a requirement to write ES5 source code then `async..await` is preferable. This is what the paragraph in the question says about.

Comment: Thank you so much Estus Flask.I learned little about asunc..await today.

Comment: You’re welcome. Notice that async..await is just syntactic sugar for promises. Everything that’s written with it can be written with plain promises in es5/es6. It’s just makes things much more convenient in some cases, this includes asynchronous loops like the one that was shown.