# The following function runs perfectly in Chrome console but not inside my javascript file. Can anyone point out the error?

Tags: javascript

```
let finalQuestionList = []; 
let questions1 = [];
let questions2 = [];
let questions3 = [];

const QuestionsPerSection = 1; 

   fetch("questions_1.json")
    .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
    })
    .then((loadedQuestions) => {
        questions1 = loadedQuestions;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
    });

fetch("questions_2.json")
    .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
    })
    .then((loadedQuestions) => {
        questions2 = loadedQuestions;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
    });

fetch("questions_3.json")
    .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
    })
    .then((loadedQuestions) => {
        questions3 = loadedQuestions;
        // startGame();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
    });
```

The above functions is used to fetch questions from a json file and store them in a local variable

```
        generateQuestionsList = () =>{
        
        for (var i = 0; i < QuestionsPerSection; i++) {
            let questionIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * questions1.length);
            finalQuestionList.push(questions1[questionIndex])
            questions1.splice(questionIndex, 1);
        }
        
        for (var i = 0; i < QuestionsPerSection; i++) {
            let questionIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * questions2.length);
            finalQuestionList.push(questions2[questionIndex])
            questions2.splice(questionIndex, 1);
        }
    
        for (var i = 0; i < QuestionsPerSection; i++) {
            let questionIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * questions3.length);
            finalQuestionList.push(questions3[questionIndex])
            questions3.splice(questionIndex, 1);
        }  
        return 1;
    };
```

After running "generateQuestionsList" in my script, finalQuestionList shows "**undefined**" as it content.
Pls Note. - This function **works perfectly** when I run it manually in chrome console.

Below is the json file structure
[
{
"question": "1Inside which HTML element do we put the JavaScript??",
"answers": {

```
              "A": "<script>",
              "B": "<javascript>",
              "C": "<js>",
              "D": "<scripting>"
              },
    "correctanswer": "A"
  },
  {
    "question": "1What is the correct syntax for referring to an external script called 'xxx.js'?",
    "answers":{
                "A": "<script href='xxx.js'>",
                "B": "<script name='xxx.js'>",
                "C": "<script src='xxx.js'>",
                "D": "<script file='xxx.js'>"
              } ,   
    
    "correctanswer": "C"
  },
  {
    "question": "1How do you write 'Hello World' in an alert box?",
    "answers":{
                "A": "msgBox('Hello World');",
                "B": "alertBox('Hello World');",
                "C": "msg('Hello World');",
                "D": "alert('Hello World');"
              } ,   
    
    "correctanswer": "D"
  }
]
```

Comment: "_runs perfectly in Chrome console_" The console [can be misleading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429203/weird-behavior-with-objects-console-log).

Answer (score 0):

I would rather leave a comment below your question, but sadly I don't have enough reputation to do so.
Are you sure you call `generateQuestionsList` function **after** your data from json files is processed? It looks like you are trying to retrieve items from arrays before they are filled with data, so they are empty at that moment, thus you get `undefined`.

If so, try something like:

```js
let finalQuestionList = []; 
let questions1 = [];
let questions2 = [];
let questions3 = [];

const QuestionsPerSection = 1; 

let promise1 = fetch("questions_1.json")
    .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
    })
    .then((loadedQuestions) => {
        questions1 = loadedQuestions;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
    });

let promise2 = fetch("questions_2.json")
    .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
    })
    .then((loadedQuestions) => {
        questions2 = loadedQuestions;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
    });

let promise3 = fetch("questions_3.json")
    .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
    })
    .then((loadedQuestions) => {
        questions3 = loadedQuestions;
        // startGame();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
    });
    
Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(() => {
  generateQuestionsList();
});
```