# JS chrome console array not expanding

Tags: javascript, console, google-chrome-devtools

When I print an array, it shows up as a 100 element array of objects, but when I expand it, it doesn't expand. Instead, there is a blue info icon that says "Value below was evaluated just now", and the arrow changes direction. The problem is still there even if I clone my array when printing (which was an answer in another SO question).

I am actually using node.js with chrome debugger but I think the issue is the same. Here is my code

```
const axios = require('axios');

axios.get("https://--------")
  .then(function(response) {
    let data = response.data;
    console.log(data.slice(0, 100));
  });
```

axios just sends http requests.

I've read:
[Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays)
[Weird behavior with objects & console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429203/weird-behavior-with-objects-console-log)

Comment: There are two explanations I think: a bug in Chrome/node.js or the code running at that time was accidentally different. Anyway, try JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)) or do a deepCopy. Or maybe the array is just 100 `undefined` values.

Comment: yeah i tried JSON.parse(JSONstringify(...)) but it didn't work. Also if I just print it as a JSON string it is not undefined

Answer (score 1):

Your problem might be occurring because **you are trying to expand the data structure after the debug session has ended**.

Try add a `debugger;` after your console log to ensure you are expanding that array during your debug session.