# The Chrome DevTools console dosent work right?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

[The Chrome DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TiuS.jpg)

```
let arrForSplice = [1,2,3,7]
let deletedItems = arrForSplice.splice(3,0,[3,4]);
console.log(arrForSplice)
```

why it work this way?

Comment: look at the  The Chrome DevTools picture

let arrForSplice = [1,2,3,7]
let deletedItems = arrForSplice.splice(3,0,[3,4]);

must give me
Array [1, 2, 3, Array [3, 4], 7]

but chrome devtools console if to uncover show array with length 3, it imposible

Comment: Ah, it's this: [Weird behavior with objects & console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23429304)