# Unexpected behaviour showing in Javascript Object logged to console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, console

Is anyone able to explain why I might see the below in my console? I am debugging a project with some url building issues - namely that the date part populates fine from a date picker and then resets without known cause when other parameters are edited.

As part of debugging I tried logging out an involved object and noted that the 'suggestedValue' key has a value that is different in the headline values versus the expanded version in the console. Any insight into why or how this would happen is appreciated.

I'm not looking for help on the overall issue, just some insight into this sort of behaviour within an object, it's not something I've ever seen.

[image]

Comment: [Weird behavior with objects & console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23429203)?

Comment: "*and noted that the 'suggestedValue' key has a value that is different in the headline values versus the expanded version in the console*" wait, what's the difference? Both say `2021-03-21` EDIT: I'm blind, one is 21, the other 22. Lazy console it is.