# Typeof behaves differently in normal and export functions

Tags: javascript

I want to check in JS with typeof, if function is declared. The code, where this check takes place, is in another file, that is imported. But, if the function does not exist, typeof throws an error instead of returning "undefined", when called in external function.

The main script:

```
import * as module from 'module.js';

function testUndefined()
{
    console.log(typeof dummyFunction);//writes "undefined" as expected
}

function main()
{
    testUndefined()
    module.testUndefinedExport()
}
```

module.js

```
export function testUndefinedExport()
{
    console.log(typeof dummyFunction); //throws an error "Reference to undeclared variable 'dummyFunction'"  
}
```

Why the behaviour is so different?

Comment: As a sidenote, `(typeof dummyFunction).toString()` the call to `toString()` is useless for even two reasons. First `typeof` **always**  returns a `string`, second `console.log` automatically calls `toString()` on non-primitive, non-string-arguments.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, node 15.6 esm loader. Are you sure, this is not a linter error, but actually an exception?

Comment: @connexo "*second console.log automatically calls toString() on non-primitive, non-string-arguments.*" not necessarily. It tends to happen on places where the log is textual (e.g., Node) but in the browser the console is perfectly happy to take an object reference and print that then evaluate it later. Often leading to [Weird behavior with objects & console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23429203). Even on Node.js printing an object will likely convert it for display, otherwise it'd just print `"[object Object]"` (the default result of `.toString()` on an object).