# Javascript destructuring interrogation

Tags: javascript, destructuring

I have the following javascript code:

```
const {
  tr,
  selection: { $from }
} = state;
```

I understand that the above is a destructuring construct but I am unsure about the `: { $from }` part as there are no `$from` property in the `selection` object (see screenshot)...

There is no `tr` in `state` either...

Can someone please explain?

[image]

**edit**: Actually, there is indeed a `$from` property (see screenshot) but it is nested. Can someone please explain how desctructuring can fetch nested properties?

[image]

Comment: Do you get any value for `$from`? If you do, that suggests there *was* such a property. Maybe it's just missing later. Beware [Weird behavior with objects & console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23429203)

Comment: @VLAZ Yes I indeed get a value for `$from`. Let me read the link you provided. :-)

Comment: "*Can someone please explain how desctructuring can fetch nested properties?*" it cannot. Not with the nesting shown in that screenshot because that's a completely different property that happens to share the same name.

Comment: The reason I did not find the `tr` property in `state` and the `$from` property in `state.selection` is because these were in the `__proto__` 's **getters**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Destructuring allows you unpack object fields into new variables.

For example, if your `state` object looks like this:

```js
state = {
   selection: {
       ranges = [1,2,3],
       $head = "abc"
   },
   storedMarks = 99
}
const { selection, storedMarks } = state // destructuring

console.log(selection) // > { ranges:.., $head... } 
console.log(storedMarks) // > 99
```

New variables `selection` and `storedMarks` has been created.

If you are trying to retrieve `tr` and `$from`

```js
const {
  tr,
  selection: {
     ranges: [
        $from: myFromValue
     ]
  }
} = state;

console.log(tr); // will print your tr value that is in `state` object, if it exists
console.log(myFromValue); // will print your $From value
```