# vue 3 composition api, passing data and making it reactive

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

In my component I have a simple select menu with two options ("all", and "Investment"). The idea here is to get an array of data from a composable, and display on screen each row of this data. If I select "all" in the menu it displays all rows, if I select "Investment" it will filter the data and display only those with obj.link == "usa".

Once I fetch the data and bring it into my component, if I console.log the data, it works fine. If I console.log the data after i filter it, I get an empty array.

I have then tried to hard code the data in my component and test the filter function, and it works fine. So the error comes from how I am getting my data and how I try to use it. I have tried to use different hooks such as onMounted, but was unsuccessfull.

Here is a minimalistic sample of my code.
Any suggestion or advice is more than welcome

The composable that fetches the data from my database looks like this:

```
import {ref} from 'vue'
import { projectFirestore } from '../firebase/config'
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

const getActorDocs = () => {
    const actorDocs = []
    const error = ref(null)

const loadActors = async () => {
        try {
            const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(projectFirestore, "actors"));
            querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                actorDocs.push(doc.data())
            }) 
        } catch (err) {
            error.value = err.message
            console.log(error.value)
        }
    }

    return { actorDocs, error, loadActors} 
}

export default getActorDocs
```

My component:

```
<template>
    <div class="col-2">
            <span class="lbl">MA</span>
            <select v-model="selectedMA" class="form-select"  >
                <option value="all">all</option>
                <option value="Investment">Investment</option>
            </select>
    </div>

    <p v-for="obj in actorListTest2" :key="obj" :value="obj"> {{obj}} </p>
<template/>


<script >
import {onMounted, onBeforeMount, ref} from 'vue'
import getActorDocs from '../../composables/getActorDocs'
export default {
setup(){

    const selectedMA = ref("Investment")
    const error = ref(null)
    const {actorDocs, loadActors} = getActorDocs()
    var actorListTest1 = actorDocs
    const actorListTest2 = ref([])
    
    loadActors() // loads actors array into actorDocs
    actorListTest2.value = actorListTest1


    console.log(actorListTest1) // <----- prints correctly (see image below)
    if(selectedMA.value === "all"){
      actorListTest2.value = actorListTest1
    }else{
      actorListTest2.value = actorListTest1.filter(obj => {
        return obj.link == selectedMA.value
      })
    }
    
    console.log(actorListTest2.value)  // <----- prints undefined !
    


    return { error, selectedMA, actorListTest2}
    }//setup
}
</script>
```

This is the output of console.log(actorListTest1):

[image]

Then this is the output of console.log(actorListTest2) after filtering :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known problem with `console.log`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429203/weird-behavior-with-objects-console-log?), it shouldn't be used to debug object values in real time.

`actorDocs` is not reactive and won't work correctly with asynchronous operations in Vue. Side effects are supposed to be done in lifecycle hooks, e.g.: `mounted`.

In current state `getActorDocs` isn't ready to be used with composition API because it's limited to follow promise control flow in order to avoid this race condition:

```
onMounted(async () => {
    await loadActors();
    console.log(actorListTest2.value);
});
```

A correct way to avoid this is to make `actorDocs` reactive array or a ref:

```
const actorDocs = reactive([]);
```

In case there's a need to access filtered value in side effect, e.g. `console.log`, this is done in a watcher

```
const actorListTest2 = computed(() => actorDocs.filter(...));

watch(actorListTest2, v => console.log(v));   

onMounted(() => {
    loadActors();
});
```