# Object property from state visible in console.log, but "undefined" when accessed directly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Apologies, I feel like this has been covered thoroughly but none of the Similar Questions quite seem to hit the mark. I've worked with React a lot in the past, but it's been a while and I'm feeling a little rusty...

So in my React (Native, but I don't think that's relevant) app, I have a data object which I pull from an external JSON file, which I store part of in component-level state. This state contains an array of objects `questions`.

I have a useEffect where I modify this state object by adding another property `shuffled_answers` to each element of the array and set this back to state. This all seems to work totally fine (inspected using console logs and react dev tools and state looks exactly as I would expect).

For some reason though, when I try to use this new property in my JSX it's consistently undefined. Even if I try to conditionally render based on the existence of the property.

Here's an abridged version of my component, any thoughts very welcome. Note that in the 2 console logs in my JSX, in the top one I can see the populated `shuffled_answers` property within my object. But in the console log just below it, where I call the property directly, it returns `undefined`. Same goes with the conditionally rendered `<View>` a few lines below, this never renders even though I can see that `shuffled_answers` is part of the object.

```
const QuizScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const selectedLevel = useSelector(state => state.progress.selectedLevel)
  const currentQuestionIndex = useSelector(
    state => state.progress.currentQuestion,
  )

  /* Set up some local state (i.e. just for this active quiz view) which doesn't need to be in redux */
  const [questionAnswered, setQuestionAnswered] = useState(false)
  const [activeQuiz, setActiveQuiz] = useState(
    quizData.quizzes.find(quiz => quiz.id === selectedLevel),
  )

  useEffect(() => {
    /* Create an array of shuffled answers within local state */
    let mutableActiveQuiz = activeQuiz

    mutableActiveQuiz.questions.map((question, i) => {
      const allAnswers = [
        question.correct_answer,
        ...question.incorrect_answers,
      ]

      const shuffledAnswers = allAnswers
        .map(value => ({ value, sort: Math.random() }))
        .sort((a, b) => a.sort - b.sort)
        .map(({ value }) => value)

      mutableActiveQuiz.questions[i].shuffled_answers = shuffledAnswers
    })

    setActiveQuiz(mutableActiveQuiz)
  }, [])

  /* ... */

  return (
    <View>
      {console.log(activeQuiz.questions[currentQuestionIndex])}
      {console.log(activeQuiz.questions[currentQuestionIndex].shuffled_answers)}
      <Text>Level {selectedLevel}</Text>
      <Text>Question {currentQuestionIndex + 1}</Text>

      <View>
        <Text>
          {decode(activeQuiz.questions[currentQuestionIndex].question)}
        </Text>

        {activeQuiz.questions[currentQuestionIndex].shuffled_answers && (
          <View>
            {activeQuiz.questions[currentQuestionIndex].shuffled_answers.map(
              (answer, i) => {
                return (
                  <Button
                    key={i}
                    title={answer}
                    onPress={() => submitAnswer(answer)}
                  />
                )
              },
            )}
          </View>
        )}

        {questionAnswered && (
          <View>
            <Button
              title='Next Question'
              onPress={() => {
                dispatch(nextQuestion())
                setQuestionAnswered(false)
              }}
            />
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: Possible relation: [Is Chrome’s JavaScript console lazy about evaluating objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4057440) | [Weird behavior with objects & console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23429203)

Comment: I've "fixed" this for now by just replacing the local state logic which I was trying to use within the component with dispatches to my redux store. I'd still love to know what was going on here though as I really can't figure it out.