# Not able to stop the spinner on page when lengthy response is coming using Angular and Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I am facing one issue. In my application my page is requesting to server which is run by `Node.js` to fetch `2000` record at a time. Here the records are coming from `Node` but in dev tool console its not expanding and also I have some loader implementation that is not stopping even after receiving the response. I am explaining whole code below.

> demo.component.ts:

```
onFileSelect($event) {
    const file = $event.target.files[0];
    const fileName = file.name;
    const fileExtension = fileName.replace(/^.*\./, '');
    if (fileExtension === 'ubot') {
      this.loginService.startSpinner(true);
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('cec', this.cec);
      formData.append('screenName', this.intFlow);
      formData.append('fileCategory', 'payload');
      formData.append('file', file);
      this.intentService.reverseFile(formData).subscribe(async (res: any) => {
        console.log('response', res);
        console.log('succ', res.status);
        if (res && res.status === 'success') {
          this.loginService.startSpinner(false);
          this.intentService.intentData = '';
          this.resettoOriginalState();
          this.cdref.detach();
          await this.repopulateDataFromFile(res.body);
          (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('fileuploader')).value = "";

        }
        else {
          this.loginService.startSpinner(false);
          this._notifications.create(res.msg, '', this.errorNotificationType);


          (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('fileuploader')).value = "";
        }
      });
    } else {
      this.loginService.startSpinner(false);
      this._notifications.create('Please choose a file', '', this.errorNotificationType);


    }
  }
```

Here I am requesting to server through one service which is given below.

```
reverseFile(value) {
    // const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
    // let headers = new HttpHeaders({
    //   Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
    // })
    return this.http.post(this.nodeAppUrl + 'reverseFile', value,{ observe: 'response'})
    .pipe(
      tap((res:any) => this.loginService.validateToken(res)),
      map((res:any) => {
        return res.body
      })   
    )
  }
```

Here the angular is requesting the spinner is starting and after some sec the response also coming from `Node.js` but as we have the line `this.loginService.startSpinner(false);` after success message but the spinner is still running.

Here in the response we have more than 2000 records which is in nested array of object format and we are populating the record using `this.repopulateDataFromFile(res.body);` method. I am attaching below the screen shot of console tool.

[image]

Even the status is success I am not able to stop the spinner and also I am not able to expand the record the console which is showing `the value was evaluated upon first expanding......`.

Can anybody please give any help why it is happening and how to resolve this.

Comment: Try using `console.log('response', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res)))`

Comment: @HarshitRastogi, I will try your solution but when the record is less like 10 or 20 everything working fine.

Comment: You can read more about such behaviour of console [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23429304/8269427)

Comment: Ok, but issue is even the response status is access  the spinner is not stopping.

Comment: @HarshitRastogi, I tried your solution but same issue.

Comment: Declare a variable `const _this = this;` inside the `onFileSelect` function and then use `_this.loginService.startSpinner(false);`