# Jquery | I can't change span text

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a chrome extension. My aim is to change the text the user wrote after pressing the button

Firstly I use Jquery selector.

```
$('.deneme').html("MERHABA");
```

But there is no change. If I add console.log at the beginning of the line, I am getting the following output.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GG5hf.png)

How can I change this span text?

Comment: `Object(0)` means there was no element when your script ran ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23429203)). Use MutationObserver or setInterval to wait for the element.

Comment: @wOxxOm
`<span data-lexical-text="true" class="deneme">asdsadasd</span>` 
that is my span elements I want to change "asdsadasd"