# Andvanced brain teaser with React useEffect && JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, object, react-hooks

I faced an unordinary javascript functionality.
Below, you will see React code (more precisely: useEffect hook) compiled to javascript.

```
 (0, _react.useEffect)(() => {
    console.log("Outside", socket);
    if (socket !== null && socket !== void 0 && socket.connected) {
      console.log("Inside", socket);
      setNewSocket(socket);
    }
  }, [props]);
```

you can see two console.log's, one outside 'if' statement and one inside.

However, in browser I see only 'Outside' console.log regardless if socket appear or not:

[image]

When I removing last 'if' check (&& socket.connected), the statement passes, but socket object and its keys values does not match.

code:

```
 (0, _react.useEffect)(() => {
    console.log("Outside", socket);
    if (socket !== null && socket !== void 0 ) {
      console.log("Inside", socket);
      console.log("connected", socket.connected);
      setNewSocket(socket);
    }
  }, [props]);
```

console.log:
[image]

Problem is that as a result setNewSocket setting socket with bad values (with socket.connected: false) causes the socket not to work.

How can it be possible? Any ideas?

one more interesting functionality is this behaviour happens only when I going directly to the page where socket is used, exp.: https://myweb.com/tableWithSocket. However, if I go to the **/home** page and then to the **/tableWithSoket** via navigation menu, it seems to work ok. Also, when I resize my page via ***toggle device toolbar*** or when I close my navbar, it starts to work as well. In conclusion, it guess it starts to work when rerender happens

Comment: When you click that little arrow in the console, you read the current state of the object, not the state from when `console.log` happened. `console.log(socket.connect)` shows the value from the time when it was called, because booleans are passed by value, not by reference

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Weird behavior with objects & console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429203/weird-behavior-with-objects-console-log)

Comment: make sense. I am wondering how can I fix it? I can't use `JSON.stringify` due to `Converting circular structure to JSON` and `Object.assign` will work only for object that contain primitive values only.

Comment: You can try using `structuredClone`, but why do you want to log this to the console in the first place?

Comment: I don't want to console it, but the problem is that `setNewSocket` setting socket is without connection (socket.connection: false) what causes that socket not work in my app. Console is just for debugging

Comment: Why do you store your socket in the state? Also, you just have to wait so the socket will connect.

Comment: and `structuredClone` does not work as well, throws error `failed to execute structuredClone`. I guess because of `circular structure`

Comment: Also, don't paste images of the code please

Comment: I store it in useContext to avoid props drilling. My structure is like in this video: https://youtu.be/tBr-PybP_9c?t=5367, or very similar

Comment: Why don't follow the video then and instead try to make hacks with `useEffect`? https://github.com/WebDevSimplified/Whatsapp-Clone/blob/master/client/src/contexts/SocketProvider.js

Comment: because it is microfrontend and the same table is implemented in two different apps. So socket is provided to that table via props. In one app all work perfectly, in another, this kind of problem appears. This table is like a npm package that accept some props, one of this props is socket

Comment: Still, checking for `socket.connected` in `useEffect` won't work, because change of that property won't trigger the effect

Comment: Your right! I figured it out. Will show my solution asap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @konrad mentioned: "checking for `socket.connected` in `useEffect` won't work, because change of that property won't trigger the effect"

In other words, I can not put just `props` as a dependency here (props is an object that contain socket and some other values that was passed to component) and I can not even put a `socket` as a dependency because both of them are objects, what means they are reference type and dependency array contains a reference number that will not change even if object key/values will change.

So, I need to check specifically `socket.connected` value:

```
(0, _react.useEffect)(() => {
  if (socket !== null && socket !== void 0 && socket.connected) {
    setNewSocket(socket);
  }
}, [socket, socket !== null && socket !== void 0 && socket.connected]);
```

React code would look like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (socket?.connected) {
    setNewSocket(socket);
  }
}, [socket?.connected]);
```