# How to access the value of a ref in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js

I have an object that I am trying to log.
When I just log the object like so, the log clearly shows that there is an object in the value property:
[image]
[image]

but when I log the value, it shows an empty object.
[image]
[image]

why is console.log(recipe.value) logging an empty object when logging just the recipe shows that there IS a value?

the recipe is from composable that makes a get request.

I made sure to console.log on the onMount.

Comment: Check out the [vuejs dev tools plugin for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd). Also please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) - in general please post code as text, not screenshots.

Comment: This means that you have race condition and request data isn't ready on mount. Depending on the case, this is solved with a promise or a watcher. Likely the latter because it's the way composables are usually used

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429203/weird-behavior-with-objects-console-log?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Please post all code, including errors as code - not images. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) for an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what happened was two things:

1. I didn't return the ref inside an object in the composable. I did return `recipe` instead of return `{recipe}`

```js
import $ from "jquery";
import { ref } from "vue";

const getPost = (id) => {
  const recipe = ref(null);
    
  $.get(`https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i=${id}`,
    function (data) {
    const [meals] = data.meals;
    recipe.value = meals;
    }
  );
    
  return { recipe };
};
    
export default getPost;
```

2. Instead of onMount, I did a `console.log` with a watcher:

```
watch(recipe, ()=>{
  console.log(recipe.value);
})
```