# Variables in array from fetch become zeros on return from function with promise

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fetch-api, es6-promise

I have a function to get an array of some data from server:

```js
async GetResolutionsAsync(signal: AbortSignal): Promise<BaseReference[]> {
    var resp = await fetch(`api/Improvements/GetResolutions`, {
        signal: signal
    })

    if (resp.status >= 400)
        throw new Error(`[ImprovementsDbHandler GetResolutionsAsync]: ${await resp.text()}`)

    const data = await resp.json() as BaseReference[]
    return data
}
```

My `BaseReference` type:

```js
export type BaseReference = {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

But I get 0 values in `id` variables after `await resp.json()`

```
(8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 0, name: 'К реализации'}
1: {id: 0, name: 'На доработку'}
2: {id: 0, name: 'На перспективу'}
3: {id: 0, name: 'На рассмотрение ТС1'}
4: {id: 0, name: 'На рассмотрение ТС2'}
5: {id: 0, name: 'На рассмотрение ТС3'}
6: {id: 0, name: 'Отклонено'}
7: {id: 0, name: 'Не выбрано'}
length: 8
```

But the thing is, when I'm not putting `data` variable in return, everything works as intended. For example:

```js
const data = await resp.json() as BaseReference[]

console.log(data)

return []
```

Console log:

```
(8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1, name: 'К реализации'}
1: {id: 2, name: 'На доработку'}
2: {id: 3, name: 'На перспективу'}
3: {id: 4, name: 'На рассмотрение ТС1'}
4: {id: 5, name: 'На рассмотрение ТС2'}
5: {id: 6, name: 'На рассмотрение ТС3'}
6: {id: 7, name: 'Отклонено'}
7: {id: 0, name: 'Не выбрано'}
length: 8
```

I have a lot of the same functions to get other arrays of data, but all of them return the requested values, what can be wrong here?

Comment: This array must be mutated after your returned it. Check the references of this  function and check if the `id` of the elements has been reassigned somewhere

Comment: First of all, `console.log(someobject)` may be misleading. Read more about that here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429203/weird-behavior-with-objects-console-log Second data just doesn't magically change itself. If it's correctly received from the api but looks different afterwards, it has been changed somewhere inbetween.

Comment: Set a breakpoint after `await resp.json()` Check if the values are correct there. If they are, trace the usages of that data. Somewhere it has to be changed (on purpose or accidentally, we don't know as you don't show any codE)

Comment: what would be the console.log result if you return the data with console.log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the commentators said, somehow and somewhere the data is changing, I suppose, because I couldn't find the possibilities for these changes since the only thing I am doing with this array is setting it into state to use as certain dictionary. So now I am creating a copy of the array to put it to state, and the problem seems to be solved:

```js
iHandler.GetResolutionsAsync(controller.signal).then((resolutionsToSet) => {
    var newResolutions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(resolutionsToSet))
    setResolutions(newResolutions);
                                  
}).catch((error) => { setLoading(false); errorHandler(error, "[GetResolutionsAsync]") })
```