# Property in Pina store returns empty object after setting the value

Tags: laravel, vue.js, pinia

In accountsList.vue i call the following script where i commented a lot out because im doing a serious refactor and i wanted to isolate the problem. "balance" has a proper value and is set, i checked.

```
<script setup>
import Account from "@/Pages/Partials/AccountItem.vue";
import {UseAccountsStore} from "@/Stores/UseAccountsStore.js"

const props = defineProps({
    editMode: Boolean,
    balance: Object
})

const accountsStore = UseAccountsStore();
// console.log(props.balance)
accountsStore.balance = props.balance;
accountsStore.getAccounts()

// const balanceStore = UseBalanceStore()
// const balanceItemsStore = UseCategoryItemsStore()

function update() {
    // accountsStore.getTotal()
    // balanceStore.getGrandTotal()
}
```

This is my UseAccountsStore

```
import {defineStore} from "pinia";
import {ref} from "vue";

export const UseAccountsStore = defineStore('AccountStore', () => {
    const balance = ref(null)
    const accounts = ref([])
    const total = ref(0)

    function getAccounts() {
        console.log(balance);
        axios.get(route('accounts.index', {'id': balance.value.id}))
            .then((response) => accounts.value = response.data)
    }

    function getTotal() {
        axios.get(route('accounts.total'))
            .then((response) => total.value = response.data)
    }

    function addAccount(account) {
        accounts.value.push(account)
    }

    return {accounts, total, getAccounts, getTotal, addAccount}
})
```

What i don't get is that my "console.log(balance);" returns an empty object. I tried to use a setter but that also results in a null value. Does anyone know why? What am i doing wrong?

Also:

```
axios.get(route('accounts.index', {'id': balance.value.id}))
            .then((response) => accounts.value = response.data)
```

Gives the error

```
error:Uncaught (in promise) Error: Ziggy error: 'id' parameter is required for route 'accounts.index'
```

If i just hardcode "balance.value.id" everything works just fine

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429203/weird-behavior-with-objects-console-log?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Is does not seem to be the asychronious bahaviour of console.log if that is what you mean, my code also does not work, i updated my question. Have i missed something?

Comment: Yes, I mean that. Currently you don't debug it properly because of the behaviour described in the linked question, and the question doesn't contain https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to suggest the causes. If you rely on id, you need to do console.log(props.balance.id) and console.log(balance.value.id), or preferably use a debugger because console is a substitute for it

Comment: I use PHPStorm, that has java-script debugging by default and that helps a lot but it cannot solve some problems. I checked to see is asynchronicity is a problem but that also doesn't reveal anything.

Comment: i'm looking into chrome debugger but i have never used it, i'm a PHP programmer learning to become full stack

Comment: Adding `debugger` statement with opened debugger is the most simple way. I'd check first if `props.balance` can be asynchronously changed.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. I was setting the balance property after i initialized the stores. So i switched is around like so:

```
<script setup>
import AccountsList from "@/Pages/Partials/AccountsList.vue";
import PrimaryButton from "@/Components/PrimaryButton.vue";
import {ref} from "vue";
import AppLayout from "@/Layouts/AppLayout.vue";
import SheetItemsList from "@/Pages/Partials/SheetItemsList.vue";
import BalanceTotals from "@/Pages/Partials/BalanceTotals.vue";
import {UseSheetItemsStore} from "@/Stores/UseSheetItemsStore.js";
import {UseBalanceStore} from "@/Stores/UseBalanceStore.js";
import {UseCategoriesStore} from "@/Stores/UseCategoriesStore.js";
import {UseAccountsStore} from "@/Stores/UseAccountsStore.js";
import CreateCategoryModal from "@/Pages/Modals/CreateCategoryModal.vue";

const props = defineProps({
    'is_default': Boolean,
    'balance': Object
})

const balanceStore = UseBalanceStore()
const sheetItemStore = UseSheetItemsStore()
const categoriesStore = UseCategoriesStore()
const accountsStore = UseAccountsStore()

sheetItemStore.balance = props.balance
balanceStore.balance = props.balance
categoriesStore.balance = props.balance
accountsStore.balance = props.balance

sheetItemStore.getSheetItems()
sheetItemStore.getTotals()

balanceStore.getGrandTotal()

categoriesStore.getCategories()

accountsStore.getAccounts()
accountsStore.getTotal()

let show = ref(false)
let editMode = ref(false)
</script>
```

Now everything is working beautifully. "Big smile"