# Accessing Api Result Array Returns Undefined TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Using Omdb's api I pull film information using the film's imdbId, but for some reason when it returns the array of results, I can print the results array but when I try to access the results at their given index it returns undefined when I know for a fact there's data there.

Api call method:
[Api method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8zv7.png)

```
search1FilmOmdb(imdbId: string) {
    let filmList: ExtensiveSearchFilmModel[] = [];
    const url: string = `${this.baseOmdbUrl}i=${imdbId}`

    this.httpClient.get<ExtensiveSearchFilmModel>(url).subscribe({
      next: (result) => filmList.push(result),
      error: (error: HttpErrorResponse) => console.log(error)
    });

    return filmList;
 }
```

Console log statements:
[Console log statements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoYvU.png)

```
console.log('api result array:');
console.log(this.apiService.search1FilmOmdb(this.imdbId));
console.log('api result array[0]:');
console.log(this.apiService.search1FilmOmdb(this.imdbId).at(0));
```

Console log results:
[Console log results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KA3Yi.png)

```
api result array:
Actors: "Dee Bradley Baker, Zach Tyler Eisen, Mae Whitman"
Awards: "Won 1 Primetime Emmy. 9 wins & 7 nominations total"
Country: "United States"
Director: "N/A"
Genre: "Animation, Action, Adventure"
Language: "English"
Metascore: "N/A"
Plot: "In a war-torn world of elemental magic, a young boy reawakens to undertake a dangerous mystic quest to fulfill his destiny as the Avatar, and bring peace to the world."
Poster: "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BODc5YTBhMTItMjhkNi00ZTIxLWI0YjAtNTZmOTY0YjRlZGQ0XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyODUwNjEzMzg@._V1_SX300.jpg"
Rated: "TV-Y7-FV"
Ratings: [{…}]
Released: "21 Feb 2005"
Response: "True"
Runtime: "23 min"
Title: "Avatar: The Last Airbender"
Type: "series"
Writer: "Michael Dante DiMartino, Bryan Konietzko"
Year: "2005–2008"
imdbID: "tt0417299"
imdbRating: "9.3"
imdbVotes: "355,022"
totalSeasons: "3"
[[Prototype]]: Object length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

api result array[0]: 
undefined
```

I've tried to change the `this.apiService.search1FilmOmdb(this.imdbId).at(0)` to have a '!' operator at the end which I thought indicated that it wasn't undefined but I get the same results.

Comment: Please post code and error messages as text and not as images ...

Comment: Your api call is asynchronous but you are not awaiting it. `console.log`s can be a bit decieving in chrome because of what described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429203/weird-behavior-with-objects-console-log) and its linked duplicates

Comment: Screenshots of IDEs are unfortunately not appropriate here. [Please replace images of code/logs/errors/tooltips with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Comment: "*which I thought indicated that it wasn't undefined*"  you cannot just make an undefined object "not-undefined" by adding a `!`. This is just to turn off the typechecking of typescript (ie typescript won't complain anymore about something being possibly undefined)

Comment: @derpirscher I've pasted the code in, sorry this is my first question.

Comment: Please also read how to properly format code https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks to make your question somehow readable. But the problem is already clear, you are not awaiting the async call to your API.

Comment: @derpirscher I've tried changing my api method to use async/await and also tried making it return a promise but no luck. Do you think you could show me how you'd do it?

Comment: @Phil I'm trying my best, I don't have much experience posting questions

Comment: The last edit looks great, nice work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off @derpirscher's help I've altered the two methods to use async/await and it is working now.

New Api Method Call:

```
  search1FilmOmdbStraight(imdbId: string) {
    const url: string = `${this.baseOmdbUrl}i=${imdbId}`

    return this.httpClient.get<ExtensiveSearchFilmModel>(url).toPromise();
  }
```

New Component Method Call:

```
  async getStraightMovie() {
    let omdbSeries = await this.apiService.search1FilmOmdbStraight(this.imdbId);
    console.log('omdb results');
    console.log(omdbSeries);
  }
```