My var contains a file before post but this data is not sended
I have my var :
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "value": "41",
        "requirements": [
            {
                "id": 1,
"file": 'A 64BASE FILE'
}]

And if i check is the network of my browser, all when sended exclude the value of "file"...
Is use vueJS and my http call :
async function submitForm() {
    // Requirements
    const requirements = getFormRequirements();

    // Costs
    const costs = getFormCosts();

    console.log(costs);

    const response = await fetch(`${import.meta.env.VITE_BACK}/formsData/${id}`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ requirements, costs, formId: id })
    });

}

I have try to use a @onchange and save and i tested to pass all data in new FormData(); but this doesn't work...

Please, provide a way to reproduce. A reasonable explanation you debugged the var incorrectly and there's no "file" at the time of fetch call

I verified in the Network call http, all data of the var was sended but not the files.

I see, but this is already stated in the question, this is not what the previous comment addressed. There's no proof that file exists in costs at the time when it's accessed. Use a real debugger instead if possible. Console is the last resort for debugging and needs special care to debug objects, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429203/weird-behavior-with-objects-console-log

I have passed the data in a Formdata() and after in the post I have specified json.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
