Bug when creating a default object used for editing
I am encountering an incredibly weird bug at the moment.
const defaultCampaign: CampaignNpoCreate = {
    general: {
        campaignName: '',
        languages: [],
        urlName: '',
        campaignLogo: '-',
        approveP2P: false,
    },
    mail: {
        enableThanksMail: false,
        enableFiscalCertificateMail: false,
        thanksMail: '',
    },
};

This defaultCampaign (it's simplified a bit) serves as the basis for the creation of a campaign. After running this code:
const campaign = defaultCampaign;
console.log(campaign);
console.log(campaign.mail);

the first log shows 'mail' as having the same properties as 'general', but the second log does show the correct information. When using the campaign object in the form, it does not have the correct information either.
I've tried destructuring the defaultCampaign (const campaign = { ...defaultCampaign }) and setting the defaultCampaign to a function that returns the CampaignNpoCreate object, same result.
For context, this code is used in a Vue app.

my guess your form's v-model's mutates the object or something else mutates it

You can add code that is using this defaultCampaign, and can add a link to some codepen where this case is reproducible.

Don't use console to reliably debug objects, it works in an unspecified and counterintuitive way. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429203/weird-behavior-with-objects-console-log

Agreed with the comment above. Prefer using your Vue devtools for debugging purposes.

Right now, this is the only place I am using defaultCampaign, and the object doesn't even reach the v-model yet. I've tried skipping the defaultCampaign, and setting campaign to the object directly, but even then, the same issue persists.  Can't really recreate it on codepen unfortunately.
