Cannot read properties of null/undefined when fetching deep nested objects
I'm currently fetching an object from an api to my vue frontend. This object has many properties, even deep nested ones. For example a project object:
{
  id: 1,
  title: "My Project",
  status: {
    text: "Planned"
    color: "Orange"
  },
  ...
}

And when fetching this object, I put it in a ref() like this:
const project = ref()
const fetchProject = async () => {
  const url = "api-url"
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(url)
      project.value = await response.data

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
}

Now, when I try to call a property in the html with {{ project.status.text }} it shows the Cannot read property of null/undefined. When using console.log(project) the object is fetched correctly.
Now I know, that I can use v-if to check if the property is set, but because the object is so large, I would need to add this v-if to all the elements, that need project properties. Is there a cleaner and more elegant way of solving this issue?

What's the initial value of project? If you put {{ project.status.text }} in your HTML template then it will be read before the API gets called. Do a proper null check (preferably with a loading state) before reading project.status.text is advised.

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429203/weird-behavior-with-objects-console-log?noredirect=1&lq=1 Since all the properties appear at once when you assign a value to project.value, you'd need only v-if="project"

@HaoWu The Initial value is a Project object that I've created somewhere else, but that object only has the structure of the object with a bunch of null as values.

You do not need to await response.data, it's not an async operation. What do you see in your Vue devtools? console.log is not always a good way to solve issues. Also, don't you need to return project.value?

Since initially your project is empty you either put v-if around the whole template where project is used:
<template v-if="project">
{{ project.status.text }}
</template>
<div v-else>Loading project...</div>

Or use optional chaining operator everywhere with possible default values:
{{ project?.status.text ?? 'Default status' }}

